# represent list with no entries

Tags: haskell

very simple how would you represent a list with no entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty list is simply `[]`

For example, defining a variable that holds an empty list can be done by:

```
emptyList :: [a]
emptyList = []
```

Comment: @delnan Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware that there was a difference in terminology, however thinking of a function (mathematically) as `emptyList : [a] -> [a]` I suppose it wouldn't make sense to call something with no arguments a function.

Comment: That's not a variable either. (its value can not be varied)

Comment: @Rotsor immutable variable are still variables ! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993124/does-haskell-have-variables

Answer (score 1):

Also, `""` is an empty String, and `String`s are just lists of `Char`s.