# Defining variables inside a function Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am a huge newbie to Haskell, I actually just started 10 minutes ago. I am trying to figure out how to define a variable inside a function. Lets say I have the function

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo a = 
    b = a * 2
    b
-- Yes, I know, it doesn't do anything interesting
```

When I run it in `GHCi` I get a syntax error! How can you define a variable inside a function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/993124

Comment: Read [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com).

Answer (score 32):

There are two ways to do this:

```
foo a = b where b = a * 2
foo a = let b = a * 2 in b
```

In most cases, the choice between them is an aesthetic rather than technical one. More precisely, `where` may only be attached to definitions, whereas `let ... in ...` may be used anywhere an expression is allowed. Both `where` and `let` introduce blocks, making multiple internal variables convenient in both cases.

Comment: Hey I was wondering how you would define multiple helper variables inside a function, would you do something like `where b = a * 2, c = a * 3` or would you use an entirely different "where" statement?

Comment: @EbenCowley A single `where`/`let` will do. Use `;` to separate declarations on the same line, or read about the indentation rules to use multiple lines. (This is the meaning of the last sentence of my post.)

Comment: @DanielWagner : I am very new to haskell. so one basic question : does `foo a = b where b = a * 2` basically translates to `foo a=(/b->b)a * 2` ?

Comment: @rahulaga_dev That's a decent first approximation, but as always the truth is a bit more complicated. One difference of between lambdas and let/where blocks that's important here is that the former make their variable monomorphic and the latter don't. For example, `foo :: (Int, Double); foo = (x, x) where x = 3` works fine, but `foo :: (Int, Double); foo = (\x -> (x, x)) 3` does not.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding technical correctness, the answer is "sort of".

I think it's better to think of a variable as a function of zero arguments evaluating to a given value.

```
module Main where
import System.IO

foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo a =
  b where
    b = a * 2

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ foo 10
```

Comment: It is not a function of zero arguments. Every function in Haskell takes precisely one argument.

Comment: For more on what Magnus said, see Conal Elliott's blog post ["Everything is a function" in Haskell?](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell).

Comment: @MagnusKronqvist: Would you mind providing a document giving the documentation for that?

Comment: Functions are the values that have arrow type.  Some values do, some values don't.  But if it doesn't have an arrow type it's not a function.

Comment: @PaulNathan http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying - if you allow something informal. Also you can google "Haskell currying".

Comment: This is also detailed in Learn You a Haskell.