# Haskell - for loop

Tags: loops, variables, for-loop, haskell, immutability

if I want to express something like [just a simple example]:

```
int a = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < n; x += 1)
    a = 1 - a;
```

what should I do in Haskell, *since it doesn't have variable concept?* (maybe wrong, see: [Does Haskell have variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993124/does-haskell-have-variables))

Comment: You can do this with [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion).

Comment: p.s. Haskell has variables. They just act differently than in procedural languages.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice uuuh, like `rec x a = if x < n then rec x 1-a else ...`? great!

Comment: You also need to define `n` somewhere.

Comment: I'd argue that it depends very much on why you are looping. Sometimes, you can use a higher-order function that abstracts away the iteration. Other times, you write your own recursive functions. Still others, you don't actually need to iterate at all.

Comment: ``a = ((-1)^(n+1)+1)`div`2``.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Often, repetition that you would perform with a loop in a procedural language is accomplished with [recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) in Haskell. In this case, you should think about what the result of the loop is. It appears to alternate between 0 and 1. There are several ways to do this in Haskell. One way is

```
alternatingList n = take n alternating0and1
alternating0and1 = 0 : alternating1and0
alternating1and0 = 1 : alternating0and1
```

Answer (score 13):

There are a few options. First, you can rewrite the problem with naive recursion:

```
loop :: Int -> Int
loop n = loop' n 0
  where loop' 0 a = a
        loop' n a = loop' (n - 1) (1 - a)
```

Next, you can restate recursion as a fold:

```
loop :: Int -> Int
loop n = foldr (\a _ -> 1 - a) 0 [0..n]
```

Or you can use `State` to simulate a for loop:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State

loop :: Int -> Int
loop n = execState (forM_ [0..n] 
                      (\_ -> modify (\a -> 1 - a))) 0
```

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell instead of using loops, you combine standard library functions and/or your own recursive function to achieve the desired effect.

In your example code you seem to be setting `a` to either 0 or 1 depending on whether or not `n` is even (in a rather confusing fashion if I'm honest). To achieve the same in Haskell, you'd write:

```
a =
  if even n
  then 0
  else 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
iterate (\a -> 1-a) 0 !! n
-- or even
iterate (1-) 0 !! n
```

The snippet `iterate (\a -> 1-a) 0` produces an infinite lazy list of all the values obtained starting from `0` and repeatedly applying the function `(\a -> 1-a)`. Then `!! n` takes the n-th element.

To be completely honest, in this case, I'd also look for a stricter definition of `iterate` which does not create so many lazy thunks.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers have already explained how you would approach a problem like this functionally, in Haskell.

However, Haskell does have mutable variables (or references) in the form of [ST](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html) actions and [STRef](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-STRef.html). Using them is usually not very pretty, but it does allow you to express imperative, variable-mutating code faithfully in Haskell, if you really want to.

Just for fun, here's how you might use them to express your example problem.

(The following code also uses [whileM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:whileM_) from the [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops) package, for convenience.)

```
import Control.Monad.Loops
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef

-- First, we define some infix operators on STRefs,
-- to make the following code less verbose.

-- Assignment to refs.
r @= x = writeSTRef r =<< x
r += n = r @= ((n +) <$> readSTRef r)

-- Binary operators on refs. (Mnemonic: the ? is on the side of the ref.)
n -? r = (-) <$> pure n <*> readSTRef r
r ?< n = (<) <$> readSTRef r <*> pure n


-- Armed with these, we can transliterate the original example to Haskell.
-- This declares refs a and x, mutates them, and returns the final value of a.
foo n = do
    a <- newSTRef 0
    x <- newSTRef 0
    whileM_ (x ?< n) $ do
        x += 1
        a @= (1 -? a)
    readSTRef a

-- To run it:
main = print =<< stToIO (foo 10)
```