# Store variable valor simulator

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying the simulate a save functionality for the value of a given variables. Initially I create an empty space and then when I want to add a value of a variable, I do an update of this variable in this save space.

I want to be able to have the possibility of multiple save space, and with one to have its own variable values.

I have the following code

```
type Variable = String
type Val = Int

type Store = Variable -> Val

init :: Store
init = (\x -> 0)

fetch :: Store -> Variable ->Val
fetch store variable = store variable


update :: Store -> Variable -> Val -> Store
update s v val = (\x -> if x == v then val else init v)
```

And the execution i make is this:

```
> Main> s1 = init
> *Main> s2 = update s1 "x" 10
> *Main> s2 = update s2 "y" 30
> *Main> fetch s2 "x" 
0
> *Main> fetch s2 "y" 
30
> *Main>
```

So the problem here is that the function update does not "saves" all the variables values, just the last one.

A correct excution would be this:

```
> Main> s1 = init
> *Main> s2 = update s1 "x" 10
> *Main> s2 = update s2 "y" 30
> *Main> s2 = update s2 "z" 50
> *Main> fetch s2 "x" 
10
> *Main> fetch s2 "y" 
30
> *Main> fetch s2 "z" 
50
> *Main> fetch s2 "w" 
0
```

Comment: `s v`, not `init v`. Turn on -Wall to be warned that `s` is unused. Was this way of saving your idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993124/does-haskell-have-variables

Comment: You are redefining `s2` in GHCi as a recursive function. You clearly don't intend to do that. Try instead `s1 = init ; s2 = update s1 "x" 10 ; s3 = update s2 "y" 30 ; s4 = update s3 "z" 50` using different variables every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you actually have two problems.  You can't reuse "s2" the way you are because in an expression like this:

```
let s2 = ... something that includes s2 ...
```

the `s2` on the right hand side is not the "old" value of `s2`.  Instead, it's a recursive reference to the new `s2` you are defining.  This would cause an infinite loop if your code were correct, but you have a second bug.  Your `update` function adds a new variable definition to `init`, not to supplied previous store `s`, so it doesn't "update" anything and it never uses the old `s` it's been passed.  Instead, redefine your `update` like this:

```
update :: Store -> Variable -> Val -> Store
update s v val = (\x -> if x == v then val else s x)
```

(Note that you want `s x`, not `s v` -- `x` is the variable you're trying to look up, and if it doesn't match `v`, then you want to pass it along to the old store `s`.)  Now it will work, as long as you don't reuse any store variable names:

```
*Main> s1 = Main.init  -- use "Main." to avoid conflict w/ Prelude.init
*Main> s2 = update s1 "x" 10
*Main> s3 = update s2 "y" 30
*Main> fetch s3 "x"
10
*Main> fetch s3 "y"
30
*Main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are my hero!